# Why aren't my apps updating automatically?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, wi-fi, updates, 6.0-marshmallow

i recently bought a Nexus 5x and installed all my previous apps. Everything was ok until i realized that Play Store was not updating automatically any of the aplications. I have checked the options menu and it is set to update automatically with Wi-fi and all apps have the option update automatically activated. What can it be? If i want to have my apps updated i have to open Play Store and select Update all on my apps sections. Thanks for the help

Comment: Automatic updates are run irregularly when you are not using your phone.

Answer (score 0):

It's most probable that Play Store's background process is being killed. If you have a task manager app or any app that helps free up RAM on your device, add an exception for Google Play Store and Play Services so that the app doesn't kill these processes.

Comment: I've turn off an option at the developer menu which was supposed to be doing this, but nothing changes, the apps continue not being updated

Comment: Today i realized that when i was charging it, then it suddenly started updating everything correctly, strange

Comment: Yes. As @GiantTree already said, automatic updates do run at irregular intervals.